# Example of increasing the work per thread in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, euclidean-distance, distance-matrix

**Algorithm** :

I'm writing a program with CUDA and the problem is the following:

- Two matrices A (n * 128) and B (m * 128)
- I take the first row of A, and I compute the distance between that vector and all the rows of B, one by one.
- I write the result of each distance on a row of a matrix C, so the element C(i,j) of C contains the distance between row i of A and row j of B.
- and I proceed with the next row of A.

I've implemented it this way: I've got a grid made by ( n * m ) blocks, and 128 threads per block. ( 1 * 128 ).

**QUESTION**: The program runs successfully with the expected results but the time execution is only around 5 to 10 times faster than the one-threaded CPU version of it. So I would like to know **how to increase the work per thread before reduction in order to increase performance**.

**Kernel code (original : Not optimized)**

```
 __global__ void EuclideanDistances( float *A, float *B , float *C , int n , int m)
{
    // SIZE is equal to 128
__shared__ float accumResult[SIZE];
float sA;
float sB;

    // MAPPING
int bx = blockIdx.x;  // n
int by = blockIdx.y;  // m
int ty = threadIdx.y; // 128
int tx = threadIdx.x; // 1


sA = A [bx * SIZE + ty];
sB = B [by * SIZE + ty];
__syncthreads();


accumResult[ty] = (sA - sB) * (sA - sB);
__syncthreads();


// Parallel tree-reduction
for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride > 0 ; stride >>= 1)
    if (ty < stride)
    {
        accumResult[ty] += accumResult [stride + ty];
          __syncthreads();
    }

    // Writing results to output matrix
if ((threadIdx.y == 0))
    C [bx * m + by] = accumResult[ty];
       __syncthreads();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now, I'm using another mapping : Instead of taking a grid of `n` by `m` blocks and a block of `128` threads, I'm  increasing the number of threads within a block in order to decrease the number of blocks.

*New mapping:*

Block of `128` by `8` threads (total of 1024 threads, which is the max size)

Grid of `n/8` by `m/8` blocks

Unfortunately, it's giving wrong results ).

**Optimized kernel code (to be updated)**

```
__global__ void EuclideanDistances( float *A, float *B , float *C, int n , int m)
{
    __shared__ float accumResult[SIZE][8];
__shared__ float sA[SIZE][8];
__shared__ float sB[SIZE][8];

int bx = blockIdx.x;  // n / 8
int by = blockIdx.y;  // m / 8
int tx = threadIdx.x; // 8
int ty = threadIdx.y; // 128
int i = bx * tx * SIZE + ty;
int j = by * tx * SIZE + ty;

sA[ty][tx] = A [i];
sB[ty][tx] = B[j];
__syncthreads();


accumResult[ty][tx] = (sA[ty][tx] - sB[ty][tx]) * (sA[ty][tx] - sB[ty][tx]);
__syncthreads();

// Reduction
for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride > 0 ; stride>>=1)
    if (ty < stride)
    {
        accumResult[ty][tx] += accumResult [stride + ty][tx];
        __syncthreads();
    }

    C[bx *  m + by] = accumResult[0][tx];
}
```

**HOST CODE (allocations + kernel calls)**

```
    int main()
{
     int m = 20000; //MatrixA size : m * SIZE
     int n = 4000;  //MatrixB size : n * SIZE

     srand((unsigned)time(0));

     // Host Allocations
     float *matrixA = (float *) malloc (n * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     for(int i=0; i < n * SIZE; i++)
         matrixA[i] = (float) (rand()%100)+1;

     float *matrixB = (float *) malloc (m * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     for(int i=0; i < m * SIZE; i++)
         matrixB[i] = (float) (rand()%100)+1;

     float *results_kernel1 = (float *) malloc (n * m * sizeof(float));
     float *results_kernel2 = (float *) malloc (n * m * sizeof(float));


     //Device Allocation
     float *d_matrixA;
     float *d_matrixB;
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixA, n * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixB, m * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     cudaMemcpy(d_matrixA , matrixA , n * SIZE * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(d_matrixB , matrixB , m * SIZE * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     float *d_results_kernel1;
     float *d_results_kernel2;
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_results_kernel1 , n * m * sizeof(float));
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_results_kernel2 , n * m * sizeof(float));

     dim3 threads1 (1 , 128);
     dim3 blocks1  (n , m);
     EuclideanDistances1 <<<blocks1 , threads1>>> (d_matrixA , d_matrixB , d_results_kernel1 , n , m);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     cudaMemcpy(results_kernel1 , d_results_kernel1 , n * m *sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     cudaFree(d_results_kernel1);

     dim3 threads2 (8 , 128);   // 1024 threads per block (maximum)
     dim3 blocks2  (ceil((float)n/8) , ceil((float)m/8));
     EuclideanDistances2 <<<blocks2 , threads2>>> (d_matrixA , d_matrixB , d_results_kernel2 , n , m);
     cudaDeviceSynchronize();
     cudaMemcpy(results_kernel2 , d_results_kernel2 , n * m *sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     cudaFree(d_results_kernel2);

     // Visualising and comparing results
     for (int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++)
         std::cout << "kernel1 : " << results_kernel1[i] << "  |  kernel2 : " << results_kernel2[i] << std::endl;

     free(matrixA);
     free(matrixB);
     free(results_kernel1);
     free(results_kernel2);

     return 0;
}
```

**PS**: *I have CUDA 6.0 with a NVIDIA GTX 650 (compute capability 3.0)*

Comment: +1 for the way you asked the question, without even reading it. Great formatting and style.

Comment: two suggestions: 1) You don't need the __syncthreads(); at the end and 2) You should profile this with Nsight and see your bottleneck, in this case I believe there aren't enough computations to hide the memory latencies. I suggest you to reuse the results of fetching data and storing it into shared memory for more than just two rows per block. Check the amount of shared memory you can afford and make a tradeoff to increase the amount of computations.

Comment: In addition the `if` in `for` loop looks divergent so it should not have `__syncthreads();` in it.

Comment: Do [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  Block dimensions of 128 x `m` are not going to work unless `m` is less than 9, or 5, depending on the GPU.  The kernel will not launch if `m` is larger, which is why you get bogus results and a very fast execution time.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, the max size of a thread block is 1024 on my GTX 650. In fact, I was compiling in Debug mode since the beginning... I think that's the reason why I'm getting an important kernel execution time. I'm facing some new problems while compiling in release mode: I've just posted a a second question.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I've compiled my old kernel (first one) in release mode, but the execution time isn't so good. So I've increased my block size. Could you please take a look at it and tell me what's wrong with it ? I think I'm almost done with this program.

Comment: plz help, I'm still struggling on that kernel...

Comment: If you post complete codes, that I can copy, paste, compile, and run, and see your results (*both* for the first kernel, to see the results you are expecting, and the second kernel, to see the problem) I'll take a look.  In fact, SO expects: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "   Synthesize whatever data you need in the program to generate results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert, I've just copy-pasted a host code that calls both of these 2 kernels and compare them. The results of kernel2 must should be equal to those of kernel1. ps: Add the `#define SIZE 128`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems your question has 2 components:

1. why isn't my second kernel working?
2. how do I make my code run faster?

> Why isn't my second kernel working?

You had several issues:

1. indexing problems in initial calculation of `i`, `j` as well as the index for storing the `C` value.
2. [violation of usage](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions) of `_syncthreads()` inside a conditional block

item 1 was the key element to get the code working.

> How do I make my code run faster?

This is more involved.  First of all, your attempt at "increasing work per thread" didn't do anything of the kind, it was merely an increase in the number of threads per block (from 128 to 8*128).  Each thread was doing approximately the same amount of work.  Furthermore, in the process of going to a 2D threadblock for this attempt, I believe a couple of bad things happened:

1. various coalescing and shared-memory-bank-conflict load and store patterns were broken.
2. effective occupancy went down, due the amount of shared memory required per block.

The net effect of the second kernel was to approximately double the execution time.  So that is not what we want.

However, increasing work per thread may be a good idea, along with using shared memory, as well as trying to preserve good (global, shared) memory access patterns, as well as allowing for increased occupancy.

What follows is a work-in-progress along those lines.  The following code has your second kernel fixed, along with timing infrastructure, as well as full data verification, as well as 2 new kernels.  The first new kernel (#3) is what I would call a "naive" kernel.  It simply allocates one thread per output point, and each thread loops through the necessary vectors, computing its individual result.  No usage of shared memory, or even much attention to coalescing or any other optimization.   However with a tweak to threadblock configuration (16,16) -> (8,32) threads, which I observed from @talonmies answer (now deleted), this kernel performs significantly (3x) faster than your "fast" kernel.  After further thought about the (8,32) observation, I concluded that the next attempt at optimization should focus on:

1. elimination of the usage of a parallel reduction to compute the vector distance (i.e. allow adjacent threads to use a straight for-loop to loop through the vectors)
2. maximization of benefit from the cache
3. efficient usage of shared memory
4. insist on perfect global coalescing/perfect usage of shared memory for *all* reads and writes

Item 4 prompted the question in the comments "may I transpose the matrices?"  With this permission, it's possible to re-organize the data to facilitate item 4 above. Item 2 above is addressed in my "fast" kernel (#4) by loading the B vector into shared memory, while allowing the cache to mostly focus on caching the A vectors, hopefully reducing cache-thrashing (A is the smaller of the 2 vector arrays, at about 2MB - fermi L2 is 768K, Kepler L2 is 1.5MB).  By delivering A in transposed form, and effectively "transposing" B on-chip from shared memory, it's possible to use a straight for-loop to compute the vector distance, while allowing adjacent threads to have perfectly coalesced reads and writes, as well as "efficient" use of shared memory (i.e. non-bank-conflicted loads, and broadcast reads).

For my particular timing, (Quadro5000 cc2.0 GPU, CUDA 6, RHEL 5.5) I see that your "fast" kernel requires about 2 seconds, my "naive" kernel requires about 0.7 seconds, and my "fast" kernel requires about 0.2 seconds, albeit with transposed (A,C) data.

**EDIT:** I've made one additional optimization, that is to have each block compute multiple (`CHKSIZE`) B vectors at one time.   You can set CHKSIZE to 1 to see the previous result (~0.2sec).  I found CHKSIZE of 4 gave good improvement. This is an attack at attempting to exploit the data re-use of A.  With this additional optimization at CHKSIZE of 4,  the kernel time for kernel 4 drops to about 0.1 second.

Following is the code and a sample run:

```
$ cat t460.cu 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

// both M and N must be evenly divisible by SIZE, M must be evenly divisible by CHKSIZE
#define SIZE 128
#define N 4000
#define M 20000
#define CHKSIZE 4

 __global__ void EuclideanDistances1( float *A, float *B , float *C , int n , int m)
{
    // SIZE is equal to 128
__shared__ float accumResult[SIZE];
float sA;
float sB;

    // MAPPING
int bx = blockIdx.x;  // n
int by = blockIdx.y;  // m
int ty = threadIdx.y; // 128
//int tx = threadIdx.x; // 1

sA = A [bx * SIZE + ty];
sB = B [by * SIZE + ty];
__syncthreads();

accumResult[ty] = (sA - sB) * (sA - sB);
__syncthreads();

// Parallel tree-reduction
for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride > 0 ; stride >>= 1){
    if (ty < stride)
    {
        accumResult[ty] += accumResult [stride + ty];
    }
          __syncthreads();
  }

    // Writing results to output matrix
if ((ty == 0))
    C [bx * m + by] = accumResult[ty];
       __syncthreads();
}

__global__ void EuclideanDistances2( float *A, float *B , float *C, int n , int m)
{
__shared__ float accumResult[SIZE][8];
__shared__ float sA[SIZE][8];
__shared__ float sB[SIZE][8];

int bx = blockIdx.x;  // n / 8
int by = blockIdx.y;  // m
int tx = threadIdx.x; // 8
int ty = threadIdx.y; // 128
int i = ((bx*8) + tx) * SIZE + ty;
int j = by * SIZE + ty;

sA[ty][tx] = A[i];
sB[ty][tx] = B[j];
__syncthreads();

accumResult[ty][tx] = (sA[ty][tx] - sB[ty][tx]) * (sA[ty][tx] - sB[ty][tx]);
__syncthreads();

// Reduction
for (int stride = SIZE/2 ; stride > 0 ; stride>>=1){
    if (ty < stride)
    {
        accumResult[ty][tx] += accumResult [stride + ty][tx];
    }
    __syncthreads();
  }

if (ty == 0)
    C[((bx*8)+tx) *  m + by] = accumResult[0][tx];
}
//naive kernel
__global__ void EuclideanDistances3( float *A, float *B , float *C, int n , int m){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int idy = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
  float result = 0.0f;

  if ((idx < n) && (idy < m)){
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
      float temp = A[(idx*SIZE)+i] - B[(idy*SIZE)+i];
      result += temp * temp;}
    C[(idx*m) + idy] = result;
  }
}
//optimized kernel
__global__ void EuclideanDistances4( const float *A, const float *B , float *C, const int n , const int m){
  // n, A,  4000 this kernel assumes A is column-major A(SIZE, n)
  // m, B, 20000 this kernel assumes B is row-major    B(m, SIZE)
  // this kernel assumes C is column-major             C(m,n)
  // this kernel assumes number of threads per threadblock == SIZE
  // CHKSIZE is the number of B vectors that will be compute per block
  __shared__ float my_sB[CHKSIZE*SIZE];  // enough shared storage for CHKSIZE vectors of B
  int bx  = blockIdx.x; // one block per CHKSIZE rows of B (the larger input matrix)
  while ((bx*CHKSIZE) < m){ // not used, this while loop could be used to extend a block to multiple chunks
    int tx  = threadIdx.x;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHKSIZE; i++)  // load vectors of B into shared memory
      my_sB[(i*SIZE)+tx] = B[(((bx*CHKSIZE)+i)*SIZE)+tx];
    __syncthreads();
    while (tx < n){  //loop across all vectors in A
      float result[CHKSIZE];
      for (int i = 0; i < CHKSIZE; i++)
        result[i] = 0.0f;
      for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        float Atemp = A[(n*i)+tx];
        for (int j = 0; j < CHKSIZE; j++){ // compute all CHKSIZE B vectors with read of A
          float temp = Atemp - my_sB[i + (j*SIZE)];
          result[j] += temp * temp;}}
      for (int i = 0; i < CHKSIZE; i++) // store CHKSIZE results
        C[((i+(bx*CHKSIZE))*n)+ tx] = result[i];
      tx += blockDim.x;  } // continue looping across vectors in A
    __syncthreads(); // necessary to prevent warps from racing ahead, if block looping is used
    bx += gridDim.x;}
}

float comp_euclid_sq(const float *rA, const float *rB, const int size){

  float result = 0.0f;
  float temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    temp = (rA[i] - rB[i]);
    result += temp * temp;}
  return result;
}

int main()
{
     float et1=0.0f, et2=0.0f, et3=0.0f, et4=0.0f;
     cudaEvent_t start1, start2, start3,start4, stop1, stop2, stop3, stop4;
     cudaEventCreate(&start1);
     cudaEventCreate(&start2);
     cudaEventCreate(&start3);
     cudaEventCreate(&start4);
     cudaEventCreate(&stop1);
     cudaEventCreate(&stop2);
     cudaEventCreate(&stop3);
     cudaEventCreate(&stop4);

     int n = N;  //MatrixA size : n * SIZE
     int m = M; //MatrixB size : m * SIZE

     srand((unsigned)time(0));

     // Host Allocations
     float *matrixA = (float *) malloc (n * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     for(int i=0; i < n * SIZE; i++)
         matrixA[i] = (float) (rand()%100)+1;

     float *matrixB = (float *) malloc (m * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     for(int i=0; i < m * SIZE; i++)
         matrixB[i] = (float) (rand()%100)+1;

     float *results_kernel = (float *) malloc (n * m * sizeof(float));
     float *cpu_results_kernel = (float *) malloc (n * m * sizeof(float));
     for (int i = 0; i< n*m; i++)
       cpu_results_kernel[i] = comp_euclid_sq(matrixA + ((i/m)*SIZE), matrixB + (i%m)*SIZE, SIZE);

     //Device Allocation
     float *d_matrixA;
     float *d_matrixB;
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixA, n * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_matrixB, m * SIZE * sizeof(float));
     cudaMemcpy(d_matrixA , matrixA , n * SIZE * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
     cudaMemcpy(d_matrixB , matrixB , m * SIZE * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     float *d_results_kernel;
     cudaMalloc((void **)&d_results_kernel , n * m * sizeof(float));


     dim3 threads1 (1 , SIZE);
     dim3 blocks1  (n , m);
     cudaEventRecord(start1);
     EuclideanDistances1 <<<blocks1 , threads1>>> (d_matrixA , d_matrixB , d_results_kernel , n , m);
     cudaEventRecord(stop1);
     cudaMemcpy(results_kernel , d_results_kernel , n * m *sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     for (int i = 0; i< n*m; i++) {
       if (results_kernel[i] != cpu_results_kernel[i])  {printf("cpu/kernel1 mismatch at %d, cpu: %f, kernel1: %f\n", i, cpu_results_kernel[i], results_kernel[i]); return 1;}}
     cudaMemset(d_results_kernel, 0, n*m*sizeof(float));
     cudaEventSynchronize(stop1);
     cudaEventElapsedTime(&et1, start1, stop1);

     dim3 threads2 (8 , SIZE);   // 1024 threads per block (maximum)
     dim3 blocks2  (n/8 , m); // assumes n evenly divisible by 8
     cudaEventRecord(start2);
     EuclideanDistances2 <<<blocks2 , threads2>>> (d_matrixA , d_matrixB , d_results_kernel , n , m);
     cudaEventRecord(stop2);
     cudaMemcpy(results_kernel , d_results_kernel , n * m *sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     for (int i = 0; i< n*m; i++) {
       if (results_kernel[i] != cpu_results_kernel[i])  {printf("cpu/kernel2 mismatch at %d, cpu: %f, kernel1: %f\n", i, cpu_results_kernel[i], results_kernel[i]); return 1;}}
     cudaMemset(d_results_kernel, 0, n*m*sizeof(float));
     cudaEventSynchronize(stop2);
     cudaEventElapsedTime(&et2, start2, stop2);

     cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(EuclideanDistances3, cudaFuncCachePreferL1);
     dim3 threads3 (8, 32);   // 1024 threads per block (maximum)
     dim3 blocks3  (n/threads3.x , m/threads3.y); // assumes evenly divisible
     cudaEventRecord(start3);
     EuclideanDistances3 <<<blocks3 , threads3>>> (d_matrixA , d_matrixB , d_results_kernel , n , m);
     cudaEventRecord(stop3);
     cudaMemcpy(results_kernel , d_results_kernel , n * m *sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     for (int i = 0; i< n*m; i++) {
       if (results_kernel[i] != cpu_results_kernel[i])  {printf("cpu/kernel3 mismatch at %d, cpu: %f, kernel3: %f\n", i, cpu_results_kernel[i], results_kernel[i]); return 1;}}
     cudaMemset(d_results_kernel, 0, n*m*sizeof(float));
     cudaEventSynchronize(stop3);
     cudaEventElapsedTime(&et3, start3, stop3);

     // transpose matrix A
     float *matrixA_T = (float *) malloc (n * SIZE * sizeof(float));
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
           matrixA_T[(j*n)+i] = matrixA[(i*SIZE)+j];
     cudaMemcpy(d_matrixA , matrixA_T , n * SIZE * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

     cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(EuclideanDistances4, cudaFuncCachePreferL1);
     dim3 threads4(SIZE); // one thread per vector element
     dim3 blocks4(m/CHKSIZE);
     cudaEventRecord(start4);
     EuclideanDistances4 <<<blocks4 , threads4>>> (d_matrixA , d_matrixB , d_results_kernel , n , m);
     cudaEventRecord(stop4);
     cudaMemcpy(results_kernel , d_results_kernel , n * m *sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     // test for correct transposed result C(m,n)
     for (int i = 0; i< n; i++)
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
         if (results_kernel[(j*n)+i] != cpu_results_kernel[(i*m)+j])  {printf("cpu/kernel4 mismatch at %d,%d, cpu: %f, kernel4: %f\n", i,j, cpu_results_kernel[(i*m)+j], results_kernel[(j*n)+i]); return 1;}
     cudaEventSynchronize(stop4);
     cudaEventElapsedTime(&et4, start4, stop4);
     cudaFree(d_results_kernel);

     printf("Success!\n");
     printf("kernel1 : %.fms, kernel2 : %.fms, kernel3 : %.fms, kernel4 : %.fms\n", et1, et2, et3, et4);

     free(matrixA);
     free(matrixB);
     free(results_kernel);

     return 0;
}

$ nvcc -O3 -arch=sm_20 -o t460 t460.cu
$ ./t460
Success!
kernel1 : 2213ms, kernel2 : 4660ms, kernel3 : 691ms, kernel4 : 99ms
$
```

Hopefully that will get you going with more ideas of things to work on.  You may get different timings of course on your cc3.0 device.

Are further optimizations possible?  Probably.  The first target I would look at would be to figure out how to take advantage of the data-reuse opportunities on vector A. (data re-use of vector B is already handled in the kernel 4 by loading it into shared memory.  There may be ways to use some shared memory to store portions of A to make the code run even faster.)

I guess I should also mention that following the lead of the code you provided, this code is computing the *square* of the [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).  A trivial modification to the kernels can make it compute the actual euclidean distance instead (`C[...] = sqrtf(...);`)  The validation I have included, however, assumes the results are "in-range" for perfect storage of an integer quantity in a `float`.  Your test case satisfies this requirement, but otherwise the validation code would need to be modified (if `sqrtf` were used).

Comment: As I learned from @talonmies response, the performance of my "naive" kernel (#3 in my answer) will be significantly better with a change in threadblock dimension from (16,16) to (8,32)

Comment: Thanks Robert, your kernel is on average 3 times faster than mine and it gives good results (unlike talonmies kernels). Is it possible to improve it again? Actually, I would like for my kernel to be more efficient than an OpenCV function using SSE (Streaming SIMD Extensions) CPU instructions. The latter is performing as good as your kernel (I'm wondering how it's possible for a CPU...), and my purpose is to overtake it.  I'm thinking about using the dynamic parallelism feature (I have another CC 5.0 card). Would that be a good idea?

Comment: Actually I think @talonmies answer demonstrated better analysis and more code craftsmanship. I think he is a better CUDA programmer than I am, and probably better able to write a "fast" kernel for this problem.   However there are still a few avenues I would consider pursuing: 1. Configure the code for the best use of cache.  2. Determine if shared memory can be used to any benefit.  3. Consider other data representations that may perform faster.  Pursuant to item 3, is it permissible to transpose your A and B matrices from Mx128 and Nx128 to 128xM, 128xN ?

Comment: @talonmies kernels were only giving good results for the first part of the output vector, but indeed it was a pretty elegant code.

Comment: Yes it is possible to transpose the input vectors. I'm wondering how this could improve the kernel efficiency since the data are flattened

Comment: `Is it possible to improve it again?` With the permission granted to transpose the matrices, I have updated my answer to show a further improvement.  At the moment, I don't see any potential benefit from using dynamic parallelism.  You may discover some benefit there, however.

Comment: kernel 4 is performing really fastly and the results are good.Setting a cache configuration improved the efficiency too.

Comment: `fermi L2 is 768K, Kepler L2 is 1.5MB` Are you sure ? I used `cudaGetDeviceProperties` to display the `l2CacheSize` and the results were the following: `262.144 K` for cc3.0 and `131.072 K` for cc2.1.

Comment: Fermi L2 is *up to* 768K and Kepler L2 is *up to* 1.5MB.  The largest Fermi chips have 768K and the largest Kepler chips have 1.5MB.

Comment: What about his first original kernel, he did not used 2D threadblocks, so are there non-coalesced global memory accesses and shared memory bank conflicts ?

Comment: Both of these questions can be answered for you (on any code) using the [profilers](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#abstract).  Based on a quick look, the first kernel does not appear to have obvious problems with either non-coalesced loads or shared memory bank conflicts.

Comment: Based on talonmies [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903566/how-is-2d-shared-memory-arranged-in-cuda), I'm wondering if changing the 2D threadblock to `[8][SIZE]` would increase performance (Because no shared-memory bank conflict will occur)

Comment: Other code changes would be required as well. And I don't think that would eliminate the conflicts.  But you could try it, and see if the performance improves, and also profile it for shared memory bank conflicts.